# “that is men” vs. “those are men”

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Is it correct to say, "that is men"? In the case of referring to their nature or similar characteristics. Someone argued with me that it is actually wrong. Saying you can only say, "those are men". For example,

> No man can feel good when you are with a male friend for long, **that is men**.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it is acceptable; the implied meaning is 'that is the nature of men'. You would only use 'those are men' when speaking of a particular group of individuals.

Comment: _That is men_ is correct in the present context, although you are more likely to see or hear it in its contracted form:  _That's men_, often followed by _for you_: _That's men for you!_. For example, this headline to an article in the Irish Times: https://www.irishtimes.com/news/health/that-s-men-for-you-1.429405

Comment: That's not the only context where "that is men" would be grammatically correct.  For example, it might be the answer when you say to a cannibal, "This stew is pretty tasty.  What is it?"  :-)